# How to use a field from sql select in subquery?

Tags: mysql, string, integer

I'm trying to do a select query using a field in the subquery coming from the main query. 
The problem is, the field in the subquery named "**t.code**" needs to be used like a string and be under single quotation.

```
SELECT t.id, t.code, t.name,
    (select date from positions pt where pt.code = 't.code' order by date asc limit 1) as position
    FROM trips t
```

Comment: try something like this :`SELECT t.id, t.code, t.name from trips t where t.code = (select pt.code from positions pt)  `

Comment: Just don't quote your field, that's it. Instead of the value of `t.code`, you're literally telling your query to look for code which equals string `t.code`. Why did you think it'd work and that you need to quote anything?

Comment: If i don't use quotes the select takes to much time to execute. When i put the t.code between quotes, it takes only 0.3 seconds to execute. 
The field t.code is a index